# Unable to set Max and min date to date picker

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im trying to set Max and min date in my date picker as follows.

```
  UIDatePicker *picker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    [picker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    NSDate *currentDt = [NSDate date];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [comps setYear:-10];
    NSDate *minDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDt  options:0];
    [comps setYear:10];
    NSDate *maxDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDt  options:0];

    [picker setMaximumDate:maxDate];
    [picker setMinimumDate:minDate];
```

The max year has to be 10 years ahead of the current year and min year has to be 10 years less than that of the current year

But this method is not working. It displays everything.

Comment: try with `NSGregorianCalendar` instead of `NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian`

Comment: let me try.....

Comment: It is not working

Comment: I tried your code, and I got the good dates. Are you sure you are using the good instance of `UIDatePicker`? Not a `IBOutLet` or something like that?

Comment: i am not seen any issue, its works perfectly in my side,

Comment: Your code is also working good for me. Make variable picker to be global?

Comment: Ya making a global variable has solved the issue

Comment: @HaraHaraMahadevaki If as you said, the issue is not about the date creations, it's about the fact that the instance of datePicker was not the correct one shown, so don't validate the answer that doesn't point out that.

Comment: ok.... Answer invalidated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it'll work

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setYear:10];
NSDate *maxDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate options:0];
[comps setYear:-10];
NSDate *minDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate options:0];

[datePicker setMaximumDate:maxDate];
[datePicker setMinimumDate:minDate];
```

Comment: The issue is not about the date creations, it's about the fact that the instance of `datePicker` was not the correct one shown.